# What's wrong with this unit test of an async JavaScript function (via Mocha/Sinon)?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, mocha.js, sinon

I was trying to put together a small example to show co-workers but can't figure out what's wrong with this test [that I've put in a gist](https://gist.github.com/virtualandy/8e3665068469524357f7).

Essentially I want to test a function that does something async, but use Sinon's spy() functionality to assure it completes:

```
function asyncHello(name, delay, cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("running after ", delay);
    cb("hello " + name);
  }, delay);
}



suite('Mega Suite', function(){

  suite("testing async hello", function() {
    test('should call the callback', function(done) {
      var cb = sinon.spy();
      asyncHello("foo", cb);

      cb.should.have.been.called();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Thought using Mocha and done() to resolve a test that depends on an async function (setTimeout, in this case) would work, but maybe someone can point out where I'm wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Sinon for this:

```
function asyncHello(name, delay, cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("running after ", delay);
    cb("hello " + name);
  }, delay);
}

suite('Mega Suite', function(){
  suite("testing async hello", function() {
    test('should call the callback', function(done) {
      asyncHello("foo", 1000, function () {
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

There were two problems in this code:

1. You called `asyncHello("foo", cb);` which made it so that your `delay` argument inside the function was set to `cb` and the `cb` argument inside the function was undefined.
2. Even after fixing the 1st item `cb.should.have.been.called();` was called before the function passed to `setTimeout` could execute.

   You basically don't need to use Sinon because if you just set a callback to call `done()` then you know the test is successful. If there's a problem anywhere `done()` won't get called and the test will fail.

Comment: Yup, stupid mistake on my part. Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Noted about not using Sinon, but what is the 'right' way to use Sinon in a case where I do want to spy on a function that is going to make an async call?
I'm thinking of something like an integration test where I want to make sure a module makes the right call (say an http.get()) given the circumstances (i.e. cache miss, so go get some data). But I may not want to hit the network in the test all the time.